# Electromagnetism Current Equation

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-current, charge, vectors

In my book(Field and Wave Electromagnetics), it says that $ \Delta I= \Delta Q / \Delta t = \vec J \cdot \Delta \vec s  $. My understanding is that $\Delta$ can be replaced by $d$ which represents the differential(infinitesimally small amount)  of (something). Thus, this equation becomes $dI=dQ/dt=\vec J \cdot d \vec s$. We integrate both sides and get $I=\int \vec J \cdot d\vec s=\int dQ/dt$. But I know that $I=-dQ/dt$ not $\int dQ/dt$.  Can someone clear this confusion with the deltas and the differentials.

Comment: I don't have that book, but looking at the answer by @SuzuHirose it's apparent that your $dI$ should simply be $I$.

Comment: @garyp Why is that the case ? I always thought that I can just turn $\Delta$ into $d$.

Comment: You *can* make that replacement as long as you are consistent with its use.  In $\Delta I = \vec{J}\cdot\Delta\vec{s}$ the $\Delta I$ represents a current over a small region of *area* $\Delta\vec{s}$.   Later you use it as if it represents the current during a small interval of *time*.

Answer (score 0):

The first equation, $\Delta I= \Delta Q / \Delta t$, should be $I= \Delta Q / \Delta t$. The current is the amount of charge flowing per unit time. I'm not sure what the $\Delta$ in $\Delta I$ is doing there at all, but it seems to be an error.

I looked this book up online, and it appears that this is from equation 5-1 on page 173 (second edition). Notice that the integral in equation 5-6 (page 174) is actually over the surface, so he seems to be using $\Delta I$ to mean an element of current through a particular part of a surface. Thus the time integral of $\Delta I$ doesn't make sense.

Comment: Then do you think it seems to be an error ?

Comment: Also, its on page 199-200 (2nd edition).

Comment: @user2466887 - I've tried to answer whether it's an error in the second paragraph of my answer.

Comment: It doesn't make much sense but I don't get why the $\Delta$ doesn't change into $d$.